# OpenLDAP switch from SHA1 to SHA512

Tags: sha1, openldap, sha512

I'm trying to upgrade an OpenLDAP servers userPassword from SHA1 to SHA2. Apparently, OpenLDAP can set contain multiple [passowrd storage](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/guide.html#Password%20Storage) methods. Ideally, I would like to add SHA512 but keep the SHA1 until all users have a chance to upgrade their password. Apparently, OpenLDAP will check each one of the password hashes to see if it matches. Currently I have:

```
userPassword:
{SHA} adq0a8108
```

I want:

```
userPassword: 
{SHA} aduas08du
{SHA512} a2uieuqi
```

I've been reading through the documentation but have been unable to figure this one out. Any assistance would be very much appreciated. I would think it would be a common fix due the vulnerabilities with SHA1. I have tried using ApacheDirectoryStudio set a SHA512 password but then the new value doesn't work.

Comment: You have tried exactly what and how?

Comment: Never mind, figured out. The server needs a new OpenLDAP build that supports SHA512. Going to build dev server and transfer data.

Answer (score -1):

Check using Apache Directory Studio what types of userPassword hashing methods you can use by setting a new value with a different hash and trying to authenticate. If you cannot log in chances are that hash method is not supported. It turns out although this installation did not support 'SHA512' it did support 'CRYPT-SHA-512.'